# Can't Loop Cut or Subdivide Mesh created from Bezier Curve

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

I created a Mesh from making 2 Bezier Curves, joining them together, converting them to meshes, and finally connecting their vertices with edges.

Later I added a face with F, but currently it's deleted... Ultimately my goal is to Bend the Plane (which will be filled in). I tried Loop Cut (Ctrl+R) but it doesn't let me actually make any lines on it. I also tried Subdivide and it didn't show any lines that way either. Am I doing something wrong? what are my choices?

[image: b]

Comment: Hard to know. Why not just start with a cyllinder?

Comment: Hmm, I was basically tracing a curvy shape (not seen in screenshot) and I thought Bezier Curve seemed the most natural way to do that process. I didn't want the shape to be too Line-Y (aka, not curvy enough). But if you know of an alternate way to do 'trace' curvily I am interested!